# Passing sub child to Thymeleaf fragment argument

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following Thymeleaf fragment

```php-template
<th:block th:fragment="center-position (content)">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <th:block th:replace="${content}"></th:block>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

I want to use the fragment in the following way where the argument is the children of the `th:replace` `div`.

```php-template
<div th:replace="~{building_blocks :: center-position (...)}">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</div>
```

Resulting in

```php-template
<div class="flex flex-col items-center">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</div>
```

One way I could think of is like this

```php-template
<div th:replace="~{building_blocks :: center-position (~{:: [div.param-pass]})}"><div class="param-pass">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>World</h2>
</div></div>
```

But this means I would need unique class names for each fragment replacement.